# Prove that $(D_1f)(\textbf{x})=0$ implies that $f(\textbf{x})$ is only dependent on $x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, partial-derivative

I came across this problem in Baby Rudin:

> If $f$ is a real function defined in a convex open set $E\subset \mathbf{R}^n$ into $\mathbf{R}^m$ and if $D_1f(\mathbf{x})=0\ \forall x\in E$, prove that $f(\textbf{x})$ depends only on $x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n$.

---

**My Attempt**:

We only need consider real-valued $f$, since proving that the proposition is valid for the components is enough.

If $f(\textbf{x})$ depends only on $x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n$, then

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)=f(x_1',x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)$$

for all $\textbf{x}\in E$.

Let $D_1f(\textbf{x})=0$. We proceed by contradiction. Suppose this is not the case and there exist some $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}$ which differ only by their first coordinate such that $f(\textbf{x})\neq f(\textbf{y})$. Consider the line segment joining $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$. Since $E$ is convex, this segment is contained in $E$. Then using the mean value theorem we can say that $\exists \theta\in (0,1)$ such that

$$\frac{f(\textbf{x})-f(\textbf{y})}{x_1-y_1}=D_1f(\theta\,\textbf{x}+(1-\theta)\,\textbf{y})$$

Since both the numerator and the denominator are non-zero, we can conclude that $D_1f(\theta\,\textbf{x}+(1-\theta)\,\textbf{y})\neq 0$. This is a contradiction, however, and we can conclude that $f$ is not dependent on $x_1$.

---

**Qualms:**

I have no idea if the proof is correct, and I'm not sure if the argument is rigorous enough. Can the mean value theorem be used in this manner?

Comment: I think your procedure is OK. I have another idea: take a first order Taylor apeoximation of $f(x)$ around $x_1$ for an arbitrary $x_1$.

Comment: "$f'(x)$"? I doubt it...

Comment: @Paresseux Nguyen Can you explain where I went wrong?